# Can i make Intellij compile single package?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was wondering if it is possible to make intellij compile a single pacakge, and make it ignore the rest of the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version of IntelliJ I have (14, Community Edition, Windows 7), I can right-click the package, and in the context menu, I can choose "Compile '<package-name>'".  The shortcut key sequence present there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd>, which compiles the highlighted package.